# Prevent DotNetZip to create extra folder

Tags: c#, zip, directory, dotnetzip, ionic-zip

I have use the below snippet code to make zip folder by `Ionic.zip`:

```
string lastFolder = packageSpec.FolderPath.Split('\\')[packageSpec.FolderPath.Split('\\').Length - 1];
string zipRoot = packageSpec.FolderPath + "\\Zip" + lastFolder;
string fileName = zipRoot + "\\" + lastFolder + ".zip";
Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Prompt, "Spliting to zip part...");
if (!Directory.Exists(zipRoot))
     Directory.CreateDirectory(zipRoot);
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
zip.AddDirectory(packageSpec.FolderPath, zipRoot);
zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 200 * 1024 * 1024; // 200 MB segments
zip.Save(fileName);
```

it works fine to create multiple zip part but make unexpected nested folder as following desc below:
if the variables are :

`FolderPath = C:\MSR\Temp\Export_1`

`zipRoot = C:\MSR\Temp\Export_1\ZipExport_1`

`fileName= C:\MSR\Temp\Export_1\ZipExport_1\Export_1.zip`

My source is like the image below:

[image]

1- is my source folder with it's staff to zip

2- is zip folder will contains 1 `zip.AddDirectory(packageSpec.FolderPath, zipRoot);`

**But I am ending up with :**

[image]

so these folders `MSR->Temp->Export_1->ZipExport_1->ZipExport1` are extera which means Export_1.zip should have directly source folder not that nested extra folders .

does anybody knows how I can change that snippet code to do it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this based on the [documentation link](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html) (look for AddDirectory with 2 parameters):

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    // files in the filesystem like MyDocuments\ProjectX\File1.txt , will be stored in the zip archive as  backup\File1.txt
    zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX", "backup");

    // files in the filesystem like MyMusic\Santana\OyeComoVa.mp3, will be stored in the zip archive as  tunes\Santana\OyeComoVa.mp3
    zip.AddDirectory("MyMusic", "tunes");

    // The Readme.txt file in the filesystem will be stored in the zip archive as documents\Readme.txt
    zip.AddDirectory("Readme.txt", "documents");

    zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G") ;
    zip.Save(ZipFileToCreate);
}
```

Which means, Your code should look like:

```
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddDirectory(packageSpec.FolderPath, lastFolder);
    zip.Save(fileName);
}
```

Result:

```
Export_1.zip          (archive)
|-> Export_1          (folder)
    |-> Files&Folders (data)
    |-> Files&Folders (data)
    |-> Files&Folders (data)
```

**NOTE:**

It is important to use `using` syntax, as You are not destroying the ZIP file in the end, which might cause some casualties to real run of the program (like memory leak). Please check this article on MSDN -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-lang=csharp

**EDIT:**

As I wasn't really sure what is expected result, I was unable to provide what You want. But if You want no folder, why are You passing 2nd parameter then? Solution should be:

```
zip.AddDirectory(packageSpec.FolderPath);
```

Comment: Thanks, nice correction, this is very closer to my target but still create one extra folder in zip-ed folder, so can you tell my how correct  this and give some explanation why that was happened ?

Comment: Use the function with single parameter: `zip.AddDirectory(packageSpec.FolderPath);` , updated answer @Aria

Comment: Okay, I am newbie with `Ionic.Zip` anyway thanks for your help I got it. @Tatranskymedved

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question and already has accepted the answer. I am posting for those who are still searching for the easiest way to prevent unexpected nested folder creation during the final zip folder.

Instead of adding the entire directory once. Simply add files one by one and pass the empty argument.

> **zip.AddFile(filename, "");**

The final code looks like this.

```
string OutFileName = @"C:\Test\Out\final.zip";
string InDirectory = @"C:\Test\in";

using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(InDirectory);
    foreach (var filename in filenames)
        zip.AddFile(filename, "");
    zip.Save(OutFileName);
    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.